# How to sort list in R based on an attribute of the elements

Tags: r, list

I have a list of rasters in R. Each element has a different values for the `names` attribute.
For example when I do `(names(dems[[3]]))`, the result is `"srtm_sig0.9_iter100_viter50_nb_cv0"`. When I do `(names(dems[[4]]))`, the result is `"srtm_sig0.9_iter20_viter50_nb_cv0".

Now what I would like to do is to sort the list based on a substring of the names attribute. In particular the part between `*sig0.9_****_iter20*`. So for the two examples it would be `iter100` and `iter20`.

To simulate the list, one could use something like:

```
dems = vector("list", length = 5)
iters = seq(20, 100, 20)
for(i in seq_along(iters)){
  dems[[i]] = paste0("xxxxxsig0.9_iter", iters[[i]], "_nbxxx")
}
set.seed(1)
dems = sample(dems)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this approach using `stringr::str_extract()` and regex to extract the fields?!

```r
# your data
dems = vector("list", length = 5)
iters = seq(20, 100, 20)
for(i in seq_along(iters)){
  dems[[i]] = paste0("xxxxxsig0.9_iter", iters[[i]], "_nbxxx")
}
set.seed(1)
dems = sample(dems)
dems
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter20_nbxxx"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter80_nbxxx"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter60_nbxxx"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter100_nbxxx"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter40_nbxxx"


# tidy approach using dplyr and stringr
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(dems = unlist(dems))
df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   dems                       
#>   <chr>                    
#> 1 xxxxxsig0.9_iter20_nbxxx 
#> 2 xxxxxsig0.9_iter80_nbxxx 
#> 3 xxxxxsig0.9_iter60_nbxxx 
#> 4 xxxxxsig0.9_iter100_nbxxx
#> 5 xxxxxsig0.9_iter40_nbxxx

df %>%
  mutate(sig = str_extract(dems, "sig\\d+\\.\\d+"),
         iter = str_extract(dems, "iter\\d+")) %>% 
  arrange(sig, iter)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   dems                      sig    iter   
#>   <chr>                     <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1 xxxxxsig0.9_iter100_nbxxx sig0.9 iter100
#> 2 xxxxxsig0.9_iter20_nbxxx  sig0.9 iter20 
#> 3 xxxxxsig0.9_iter40_nbxxx  sig0.9 iter40 
#> 4 xxxxxsig0.9_iter60_nbxxx  sig0.9 iter60 
#> 5 xxxxxsig0.9_iter80_nbxxx  sig0.9 iter80
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## Edit

Extracting the variables, allows us also to filter/sort the initial data:

```r
library(stringr)
sig <- str_extract(dems, "sig\\d+\\.\\d+")
iter <- str_extract(dems, "iter\\d+")

# sort the dems based on the iter
dems[order(iter)]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter100_nbxxx"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter20_nbxxx"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter40_nbxxx"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter60_nbxxx"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter80_nbxxx"
```

Comment: Sounds great:)! Any idea on how to sort the initial list afterwards?

Comment: once you have extracted the iter and sig, you can use them on the list as well. Ill add to my answer,

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the number after `"iter"` using `sub`, convert it to numeric and `order` it :

```
dems[order(as.numeric(sub('.*iter(\\d+).*', '\\1', unlist(dems))))]

#[[1]]
#[1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter20_nbxxx"

#[[2]]
#[1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter40_nbxxx"

#[[3]]
#[1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter60_nbxxx"

#[[4]]
#[1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter80_nbxxx"

#[[5]]
#[1] "xxxxxsig0.9_iter100_nbxxx"
```

---

Or do this directly with `gtools::mixedorder`/`mixedsort` :

```
dems[gtools::mixedorder(unlist(dems))]
```